# Go (strings) - Trim repeated prefix/suffix substring

Tags: string, go

I need to trim a repeated prefix and suffix substring (`"%20"`) of a string.
Example: `%20%20Hello%20World%20%20` --> `Hello%20World`

The best I could come with is something like:

```
func trimPrefix(s string, prefix string) string {
    for ; strings.HasPrefix(s, prefix); {
        s = s[len(prefix):]
    }
    return s
}

func trimSuffix(s string, suffix string) string {
    for ; strings.HasSuffix(s, suffix); {
        s = s[:len(s)-len(suffix)]
    }
    return s
}

func trim(s, ss string) string {
    return trimPrefix(trimSuffix(s, ss), ss)
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it in Go?

Comment: I think that's about it, but use a `for` loop with a single condition (without semicolons): `for  strings.HasPrefix(s, prefix) {}`.

Comment: It looks like the string is percent escaped.  Consider [unescaping](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#QueryUnescape) the string, and [trimming the whitespace](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#TrimSpace) on the result.  (`%20` is space).

Comment: @icza Thanks, don't know how I missed it. This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[`strings.Trim`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Trim) does that

> Trim returns a slice of the string s with **all leading and trailing** Unicode code points contained in cutset removed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "%20%20Hello%20World%20%20"
    t := strings.Trim(s, "%20")

    fmt.Println(t) // prints Hello%20World
}
```

This works just fine if your prefix and suffix runes always appear in the same order given in `cutset` param.

If your input string may present those characters in different orders (see comments to this answer for details), then your solution is good. You can use `strings.TrimPrefix` and `strings.TrimSuffix` from the standard lib instead of rolling your own, and combine it in one function:

```
func trim(s, sub string) string {
    for strings.HasPrefix(s, sub) {
        s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, sub)
    }
    for strings.HasSuffix(s, sub) {
        s = strings.TrimSuffix(s, sub)
    }
    return s
}
```

Comment: This is not right, `strings.Trim()` will turn `"%%20Hello"` into `"Hello"`.

Comment: Note the cutset is not a "substring" but a *set of characters* that will be trimmed from the string: https://go.dev/play/p/u9iRdShA92K

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```golang
func trimSubstr(s string, substr string) (t string) {
    for {
        t = strings.TrimPrefix(s, substr)
        t = strings.TrimSuffix(t, substr)
        if t == s { // exit if nothing was trimmed from s
            break
        }
        s = t // update to last result
    }
    return t
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/eIk6A8K3Q_1